# Relevant data form_dropdown codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to post value using javascript in form_dropdown('') but it is not posting data on form.
Jquery library is loaded. On alert it display record of dep_selected

JQUERY On view page

```
function get_subdepartment() {
var dep_selected = $('select[name=txtDept]').val();
$.ajax({
    data: {
        dep_selected: dep_selected,
    },
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'addVacancy/getSubDept',
    success: function(data){ //alert(dep_selected);
        console.log(data);
        $('.subdepartment').html(data);
    }
})
```

}

Controller Page:

```
        function getSubDept(){
        if($this->input->post('txtDept')){
            echo "getSubDept > Dept: ".$this->input->post('txtDept');
        }
        else{
            echo "getSubDept > No Return";
        }
    }
```

It display "getSubDept > No Return" Please help.

Comment: Have you tried debugging with firebug/developer tools? What do AJAX network request headers show?

Answer (score 0):

Well it's obvious, that in your controller you are requesting a post value by the key `txtDept`, but you don't have that when you send data with AJAX. What you have now is:

```
var dep_selected = $('select[name=txtLocation]').val();
```

and

```
data: {
    dep_selected: dep_selected,
},
```

So you should simply change the first line in your controller method to

```
if($this->input->post('dep_selected')) {
```

I suggest you to do some reading about POSTing values with AJAX and how to work with JSON.